# How to get first value and then another subscribe method

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

I have developed a simple angular 7 web app. firebase database connectivity,
I am trying to store the first list in an array using the subscribe method and then console.log  that array.
but before that data get the array will print undefined after some time it will get data.
How can code wait for the response is done and then print that array.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DressesService {

  constructor(public firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getJoinDresses(){
   return this.firebase.list('makavana-tailor/dresses').snapshotChanges()
  }

}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DressesService } from '../../services/dresses/dresses.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-con-dress',
  templateUrl: './con-dress.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./con-dress.component.css']
})
export class ConDressComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dresses: DressesService) { }
  dressArray = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllDresses();
    console.log(this.dressArray)
  }

  getAllDresses(){
    this.dresses.getJoinDresses().subscribe(actions => {
      this.dressArray = actions.map(action => {
        return {
          $key: action.key,
          ...action.payload.val()
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question title is not clear. But if I understand your problem correctly, you are facing an issue in working with asynchronous calls. Either you have to print `console.log(this.dressArray)` inside the subscribe or return the observable data from `getAllDresses` and subscribe to it within `onInit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title is not clear. But if I understand your problem correctly, you are facing an issue in working with asynchronous calls. Either you have to print `console.log(this.dressArray)` inside the subscribe or return the observable data from `getAllDresses` and subscribe to it within `onInit()`

code :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllDresses().subscribe(data => {
         this.dressArray = data;
         console.log(this.dressArray)
    });
 }

getAllDresses(){
    return this.dresses.getJoinDresses().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        return {
          $key: action.key,
          ...action.payload.val()
        }
      })
    }))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that you show the array before it has a chance to be populated.

You know it's populated when the `subscribe` function is called.

So the easiest is to modify your code by moving the `console.log` inside the `subscribe` call:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllDresses();
}

getAllDresses(){
  this.dresses.getJoinDresses().subscribe(actions => {
    this.dressArray = actions.map(action => ({
      $key: action.key,
      ...action.payload.val()
    }));
    console.log(this.dressArray);
  })
}
```